# Django templates CSS Javascript inheritance problem

Tags: django-templates

I have the following structure

/templates/base.html
templates/index.html --- here i have inherited base.html which has JS and CSS and both working fine when this pagge is accessed

/template/app/some.html ---- i use {%extends "base.html"%} only  is getting inherted but not the CSS and JS

can any one tell what i am doing wrong

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue happens because when you are in say: `mysite.com/index.html`, your files pointed to `css/mysite.css` try to load from `mysite.com/css/mysite.css`, but when you are in `mysite.com/foo/bar.html` it tries to load from `mysite.com/foo/css/mysite.css`

The best option is to point to your CSS/JS with an absolute path, so say your CSS always loads from `/css/mysite.css` and your JS loads from `/js/mysite.js`. Notice the prepended `/` as this is what instructs the browser to always look for this path relative to the base domain.

Comment: Thanks for that reply i tried putting it like /media/app/css and /media/app/js  
accesing mysite.com/app/some.html -- which extends base.html

Its not working yet can u just elaborate. thank you